# What's the Pythonic way to report nonfatal errors in a parser?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, warnings

A parser I created reads recorded chess games from a file. The API is used like this:

```python
import chess.pgn

pgn_file = open("games.pgn")

first_game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn_file)
second_game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn_file)
# ...
```

Sometimes illegal moves (or other problems) are encountered. What is a good Pythonic way to handle them?

- Raising exceptions as soon as the error is encountered. However, this makes every problem fatal, in that execution stops. Often, there is still useful data that has been parsed and could be returned. Also, you can not simply continue parsing the next data set, because we are still in the middle of some half-read data.
- Accumulating exceptions and raising them at the end of the game. This makes the error fatal again, but at least you can catch it and continue parsing the next game.
- Introduce an optional argument like this:

  ```python
  game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn_file, parser_info)
  if parser_info.error:
     # This appears to be quite verbose.
     # Now you can at least make the best of the sucessfully parsed parts.
     # ...
  ```

Are some of these or other methods used in the wild?

Comment: There are many different options - use `logging` (e.g. just have a warning that game such-and-such couldn't be parsed), have an additional `suppress_errors` argument, ... Do you want a partially-read game to be returned? Just skipped over? Should that be an option? This is too broad to really be answered properly - you have to decide what you want your API to do (then document it!)

Comment: The third option isn't necessary; you can define a custom exception which includes whatever information `parser_info` would contain.

Comment: A nice blog post here. https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/  the question is really a matter of style  LBYL vs. EAFP. Python prefers EAFP and is more concise to raise exception or pass. I think compiling a list of exceptions back to the user before instantiating game is a better choice. Perhaps use while info.error: to keep sending the input back to the user. It is not fatal, just validation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, those *are* fatal errors -- at least, as far as being able to reproduce a correct game; on the other hand, maybe the player actually did make the illegal move and nobody noticed at the time (which would make it a warning, not a fatal error).

Given the possibility of both fatal errors (file is corrupted) and warnings (an illegal move was made, but subsequent moves show consistency with that move (in other words, user error and nobody caught it at the time)) I  recommend a combination of the first and second options:

- raise an exception when continued parsing isn't an option
- collect any errors/warnings that don't preclude further parsing until the end

If you don't encounter a fatal error then you can return the game, plus any warnings/non-fatal errors, at the end:

```
return game, warnings, errors
```

But what if you do hit a fatal error?

No problem: create a custom exception to which you can attach the usable portion of the game and any other warnings/non-fatal errors to:

```
raise ParsingError(
    'error explanation here',
    game=game,
    warnings=warnings,
    errors=errors,
    )
```

then when you catch the error you can access the recoverable portion of the game, along with the warnings and errors.

The custom error might be:

```
class ParsingError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg, game, warnings, errors):
        super().__init__(msg)
        self.game = game
        self.warnings = warnings
        self.errors = errors
```

and in use:

```
try:
    first_game, warnings, errors = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn_file)
except chess.pgn.ParsingError as err:
    first_game = err.game
    warnings = err.warnings
    errors = err.errors
    # whatever else you want to do to handle the exception
```

This is similar to how the `subprocess` module handles errors.

For the ability to retrieve and parse subsequent games after a game fatal error I would suggest a change in your API:

- have a game iterator that simply returns the raw data for each game (it only has to know how to tell when one game ends and the next begins)
- have the parser take that raw game data and parse it (so it's no longer in charge of where in the file you happen to be)

This way if you have a five-game file and game two dies, you can still attempt to parse games 3, 4, and 5.

Comment: I agree with this answer: your parser should always report its execution, but should raise exception if it cannot do its work. The upper-level code, that asked for iteration over the file, shall be aware of the possibly raised exceptions and shall react accordingly.

Comment: Accepting this now. The best answer may vary from use case to use case, indicating that my original question is rather ambiguous or open ended. The logging, warnings and generator answer are all useful, too.

Answer (score 12):

The most Pythonic way is the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html) module. It has been mentioned in comments but unfortunately without stressing this hard enough. There are many reasons it's preferable to [warnings](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/warnings.html):

1. Warnings module is intended to report warnings about potential **code** issues, not bad user data.
2. First reason is actually enough. :-)
3. Logging module provides adjustable message severity: not only warnings, but anything from debug messages to critical errors can be reported.
4. You can fully control output of logging module. Messages can be filtered by their source, contents and severity, formatted in any way you wish, sent to different output targets (console, pipes, files, memory etc)...
5. Logging module separates actual error/warning/message reporting and output: your code can generate messages of appropriate type and doesn't have to bother how they're presented to end user.
6. Logging module is the de-facto standard for Python code. Everyone everywhere is using it. So if your code is using it, combining it with 3rd party code (which is likely using logging too) will be a breeze. Well, maybe something stronger than breeze, but definitely not a category 5 hurricane. :-)

A basic use case for logging module would look like:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # module-level logger

# (tons of code)
logger.warning('illegal move: %s in file %s', move, file_name)
# (more tons of code)
```

This will print messages like:

```
WARNING:chess_parser:illegal move: a2-b7 in file parties.pgn
```

(assuming your module is named chess_parser.py)

The most important thing is that **you don't need to do anything else in your parser module**. You declare that you're using logging system, you're using a logger with a specific name (same as your parser module name in this example) and you're sending warning-level messages to it. Your module doesn't have to know how these messages are processed, formatted and reported to user. Or if they're reported at all. For example, you can configure logging module (usually at the very start of your program) to use a different format and dump it to file:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename = 'parser.log', format = '%(name)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
```

And suddenly, without any changes to your module code, your warning messages are saved to a file with a different format instead of being printed to screen:

```
chess_parser [WARNING] illegal move: a2-b7 in file parties.pgn
```

Or you can suppress warnings if you wish:

```
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.ERROR)
```

And your module's warnings will be ignored completely, while any ERROR or higher-level messages from your module will still be processed.

Comment: This is a good answer, however it's a little *too* involved for what I need, and personally, I'll probably stick with `warnings`. Also, you state that *"the warnings module is intended for **user code**, not **bad data**"* which I agree with but since I'm designing an interpreter for a language and not just a data collector, I'm not sure whether I should consider code for interpretation as *code* or as *data*.

Comment: Also, I'm looking into it right now but I *think* I'd rather have warnings look like exceptions over looking like, well, log messages. `warnings` gives a traceback-y style by default, whereas `logging` is intended for one-liner log messages.

Comment: @cat Involvement for basic use scenario is practically the same. And warnings module is typically used to generate messages like `you're using a deprecated HTTPS library which may be a security issue, please upgrade`, which is quite a different cup of tea from this situation. And formatting is fully customizable with `logging`. But of course there are many ways to skin a cat... no pun intended. :-)

Comment: I might consider using `logging` for the parser and interpreter *frontend* and `warnings` for the backend because some warnings need to be escalated to fatal exceptions, such as `integer division or modulo by zero`

Comment: right now, the `warnings` module is doing things like reporting with a full traceback about stuff like type warnings (`TypeWarning: "divmod" operator not defined for operand types "string" and "sortedarray"`)

Comment: @cat There's nothing stopping you from putting traceback into your logging messages as well - it's the question of formatting (and possibly adding an extra parameter to your `logging.warning()` calls). Warnings module does a few more things by default compared to logging, but logging can do all that and so much more that it's not even a contest. I really recommend to try out logging - it looks unassuming at first glance, but it's incredibly powerful.

Comment: Welp, I'm switching to `logging` :)

Comment: @Lav: While logging can be very useful (and it wouldn't hurt to add it), logging a problem is not telling the caller that a problem occurred -- which means the caller will try to use the faulty game it got back and probably error out somewhere else.

Comment: @EthanFurman You're mixing two different things here. A module's job is to log a problem. It is presentation-level code which decides whether to display that problem to end user, and how to display it. Using `logging` allows you to separate these two tasks. Using `warnings` module doesn't.

Comment: Logging an error *and doing nothing else* is almost always wrong.  When you call a piece of code expecting a valid answer, and that piece of code cannot provide one, logging is fine but it also needs to raise an exception.

Comment: @EthanFurman I get a feeling we're talking about apples and oranges here. You're talking about code parsing a single party. I'm talking about code parsing a list of parties, some of which may be illegal. Raising an exception in a single party parser makes sense. Raising an exception in multiple parties parser doesn't - logging a failed party and continuing onwards does.

Comment: As long as: 1) the parsing code omits the failed party; and 2) the caller is able to deal with the missing party, sure, I agree.  But the OP is talking about parsing one game at a time, so unless you propose some other changes to his API logging alone is not sufficient.

Comment: @EthanFurman If you work on this problem from bottom-up, you need to start with exceptions. If you work on this problem from top-down, you need to start with logging. Neither are sufficient alone, that's true.

Comment: I would suggest using Logbook module which is a more modern version of logging. However, if you're not using any logging in the program (other than the original requirement), Logbook may be an overkill...

Answer (score 3):

<sup>I offered the bounty because I'd like to know if this is really the best way to do it. However, I'm also writing a parser and so I need this functionality, and this is what I've come up with.</sup>

---

The [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/warnings.html) is exactly what you want.

What turned me away from it at first was that every example warning used in the docs looks like [these](http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/python/PyMOTW/PyMOTW/docs/warnings/index.html):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "warnings_warn_raise.py", line 15, in <module>
    warnings.warn('This is a warning message')
UserWarning: This is a warning message
```

...which is undesirable because I don't want it to be a `UserWarning`, I want my own custom warning name.

Here's the solution to that:

```
import warnings
class AmbiguousStatementWarning(Warning):
    pass

def x():
    warnings.warn("unable to parse statement syntax",
                  AmbiguousStatementWarning, stacklevel=3)
    print("after warning")

def x_caller():
    x()

x_caller()
```

which gives:

```
$ python3 warntest.py 
warntest.py:12: AmbiguousStatementWarning: unable to parse statement syntax
  x_caller()
after warning
```

Comment: Thanks, I already forgot this question. Before I accept, let's see if there are any other answers attracted by the bounty.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский Niklas will likely wait at least until my bounty ends, no worries

Comment: `warnings` are more about informing the user, not the calling code.  If your module depended on the correct execution of `x_caller()` it would not know that a problem occurred.

Comment: @EthanFurman thankfully, for my purposes, almost my entire module is NIH, and the mission-critical backend code is padded with `try: ... raise BadInternalCallException; except BadInternalCallException as e:print("fatal backend bug:", e)`

Comment: but then, if there's an issue with the backend, that (hopefully) gets caught by the test suite that runs before every run of the program, and quits with an AssertionError if stuff breaks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the solution is pythonic or not, but I use it rather often with slight modifications: a parser does its job within a generator and yields results and a status code. The receiving code makes decisions what to to with failed items:

```
def process_items(items)
    for item in items:
        try:
            #process item
            yield processed_item, None
        except StandardError, err:
            yield None, (SOME_ERROR_CODE, str(err), item)


for processed, err in process_items(items):
    if err:
       # process and log err, collect failed items, etc.
       continue
    # further process processed
```

A more general approach is to practice in using design patterns. A simplified version of [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (when you register callbacks for specific errors) or a kind of [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) (where the visitor has methods for procesing specific errors, see [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) parser for insights) might be a clear and well understood solution.

Comment: @cat i updated my answer and added a couple of thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Without libraries, it is difficult to do this cleanly, but still possible.

There are different methods of handling this, depending on the situation.

Method 1:

Put all contents of while loop inside the following:

```
while 1:
    try:
        #codecodecode
    except Exception as detail:
        print detail
```

Method 2:

Same as Method 1, except having multiple try/except thingies, so it doesn't skip too much code & you know the exact location of the error.

Sorry, in a rush, hope this helps!

Comment: -1 if I could: Not clean enough, in my opinion. Also, we don't want *exceptions*, we want *warnings*, but even if we promote *warnings* to *exceptions*, `warnings` and `logging` are way better than just exception handling.

Comment: @cat: The OP says nothing about wanting `warnings` and not wanting exceptions, and neither does the bounty text.