# Being pythonic with errors

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a function here that is searching for a node within a linkedlist.

```
def searchNode(self, value):
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            if curr.getValue() == value:
                return curr
            else:
                curr = curr.getNext()
        raise ValueError("Node with this value not found")
```

Is this the best way to raise an error if the node is not found? Or is the pythonic way to return an error to the calling function. For reference, this function will be called in multiple places when looking for a node(whether to delete it, or to change its value)

Comment: You might find an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357367/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-report-nonfatal-errors-in-a-parser

Comment: If your program encounters a fatal problem - trow an exception, but IMHO in this context an exception seems to be an overkill. Maybe return None instead?

Comment: I will have to handle the None from the calling function anyway, so it seems to be a roundabout of raising an error eventually no?

Comment: If you're unable to recover from this (use a default value, display a warning and continue) and you're going to throw an exception anyway, do it like that.

Comment: But if you're going to throw an exception just to catch it in the caller function, I'd avoid it.

Comment: Not finding something in a search is generally not considered exceptional, `return None` and let the caller decide if it can recover from this.

Comment: @maestromusica It's rarely useful to raise errors when you're coding all alone anyway... Except if you plan on coming back to your code later, and on re-using what you did before. You'll be happy to be raised explicitely defined errors.

Comment: Most container types in the stdlib have two ways to do a lookup, one that will raise and another that will return a sentinel value, cf `str.find()` vs `str.index()` or `dict[key]` vs `dict.get(key)`. In your above example I personnaly wouldn't consider a failed search as an error but YMMV.

Comment: Sorry, but YMMV?